# How to create clickable photo collage in android?

Tags: android, gridview, android-imageview

I want to create as per below image in that all blocks contains the image we can call it photo collage and its will also clickable. How can I make this using GridView or any other view or library.?

If anyone has any idea related to this then please suggest me the write way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question, you want to show multiple images in a grid view like pattern and they may have different sizes/aspect ratios? Right?

[QuiltView](http://www.androidviews.net/2013/01/quiltview-library/) can be used to achieve this.